# Codenameone Tensile Drag Issue

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to get rid of the tensile drag for scrolling a Container with a BoxY Layout.

Code:

```
    f.setScrollable(false);

    appendExit(f);
    String form_uuid = "";

    Container tlist = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    tlist.setScrollableY(false);
    tlist.setTensileDragEnabled(false);
    Container tocCntn = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    tlist.setUIID("toc");
    BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
    bl.setCenterBehavior(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE);
    Container tocH = new Container(bl);

    Label lic = new Label(AppState.res.getImage("Menu_Icon.png"));
    lic.setUIID("Container");
    lic.getStyle().setMargin(Component.LEFT, 10);
    tocH.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, lic);
    Label l_h = new Label("Contents");
    l_h.setUIID("typelabel");
    tocH.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, l_h);
    tlist.addComponent(tocH);


    TopicParser parser = new TopicParser();
    switch (AppState.topic_type) {
        case 1:
            AppState.typelabel = "Listening Skills";
            form_uuid = "lbg";
            AppState.icon = AppState.res.getImage("licon.png");
            brandface = AppState.res.getImage("list_girl.png");
            AppState.current_topics = parser.parse(AppState.l_topics);
            tocH.setUIID("ltoc");
            break;
        case 2:
            AppState.typelabel = "Speaking Skills";
            form_uuid = "rbg";
            brandface = AppState.res.getImage("speak_girl.png");
            AppState.icon = AppState.res.getImage("sicon.png");
            AppState.current_topics = parser.parse(AppState.s_topics);
            tocH.setUIID("stoc");
            break;
        case 3:
            AppState.typelabel = "Reading Skills";
            form_uuid = "rbg";
            AppState.icon = AppState.res.getImage("ricon.png");
            brandface = AppState.res.getImage("reading_boy.png");
            AppState.current_topics = parser.parse(AppState.r_topics);
            tocH.setUIID("rtoc");
            break;
        case 4:
            AppState.typelabel = "Writing Skills";
            form_uuid = "rbg";
            brandface = AppState.res.getImage("writing_girl.png");
            AppState.icon = AppState.res.getImage("wicon.png");
            AppState.current_topics = parser.parse(AppState.w_topics);
            tocH.setUIID("wtoc");
            break;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (final Topic topic : AppState.current_topics) {
        i++;
        Container topicC = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //topicC.setUIID("wbg");
        if (topic.getTopic_name().trim().equals("")) {
            Label l = new Label(" ");                
            l.setUIID("toclbl");
            topicC.addComponent(l);
        } else {
            Button topicB = new Button(i + ". " + topic.getTopic_name());
            topicB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    AppState.current_topic = topic;
                    showForm("player", null);
                }
            });
            topicB.setUIID("toclbl");
            topicC.addComponent(topicB);
        }


        tocCntn.addComponent(topicC);
    }
    tocCntn.setScrollableY(true);        
    tocCntn.setScrollVisible(false);
    tocCntn.setTensileDragEnabled(false);
    tlist.addComponent(tocCntn);
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tlist);
    findTypename(f).setText(AppState.typelabel);
    findTypeiconimg(f).setIcon(AppState.icon);
    f.setGlassPane(new Painter() {

        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
            g.drawImage(brandface, f.getLayoutWidth()-brandface.getWidth(), f.getLayoutHeight()-brandface.getHeight()-findTopicFooter(f).getLayoutHeight());
        }
    });
```

However it doesnt seem to work.

1. Is there any other way to achieve this ?
2. Is there a way to change the color of the scroll bar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

setTensileDragEnabled should do the trick, I assume you are seeing the tensile drag of the Form itself rather then your tocCntn Container.

Try this:

```
Form f = new Form();
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f.setScrollable(false);
Container cnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
cnt.setScrollableY(true);
cnt.setTensileDragEnabled(false);
//add Components to the cnt Container
...
f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
f.show();
```

Comment: Didnt work. Updated my question with the entire code. I have a form with two containers (Y) and one of them is scrollable

Comment: Also found that this does not work when includeNativeBool = false. Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setDefaultTensileDrag(false);
```

did the trick